# How to change height of progress bar in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I change the height of a Xamarin Forms `ProgressBar` in code? Am using Xamarin Forms V2.1.

`.HeightRequest` and `.MinimumHeightRequest` seem to have no effect. The default progress bar is so thin that it might not even be noticed.

`.BackgroundColor` does not seem to work either.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need custom renderers for this:

First create a class for your custom progress bar:

```
public class CustomProgressBar :ProgressBar
{
  public CustomProgressBar()
   {
   }
}
```

And then also add a new file for your custom progress bar renderer:

For iOS:

```
public class CustomProgressBarRenderer : ProgressBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(
     ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.ProgressTintColor = Color.FromRgb(182, 231, 233).ToUIColor();// This changes the color of the progress
    }


    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        var X = 1.0f;
        var Y = 10.0f; // This changes the height

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(X, Y);
        Control.Transform = transform;
    }
}
```

[EDIT: fixed code above as per comment]

For Android:

```
public class CustomProgressBarRenderer :ProgressBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);


        Control.ProgressTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.FromRgb(182, 231, 233).ToAndroid()); //Change the color
        Control.ScaleY = 10; //Changes the height

    }
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks so much @kishang. To get the iOS renderer to work I needed to change this.Transform = transform; to Control.Transform = transform; -- have not tried the Android one yet.

Answer (score 7):

To make the progress bar thicker, you just have to change the ScaleY property of the ProgressBar.

For example:
This code

```
<ProgressBar Progress=".5"/>
<ProgressBar ScaleY="2" Progress=".5"/>
<ProgressBar ScaleY="5" Progress=".5"/>
```

Produces this
[image]

Note that you may need to adjust your margins accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

```html
 <ProgressBar
  BackgroundColor="White"
  ProgressColor="#BCC7EF"
  Progress="0.7">
    <ProgressBar.ScaleY>
      <OnPlatform
        x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
        iOS="2"
        Android="1" />
      </ProgressBar.ScaleY>
```

Answer (score 1):

@BillF is correct basically

In the iOS renderer code try using

```
this.Control.Transform = transform;
```

instead of

```
this.Transform = transform;
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same need and on the latest version of Visual Studio, 16.5.2 I figured out that to get a bigger horizontal bar you just need to set ScaleY within the progressbar declaration inside the xml.
To avoid glitches on Android and be sure that the progress bar is not overwhelming other elements I added a margin as you can see from the declaration here below.

```
        <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message"
        android:scaleY="8"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
```

Comment: This should be the right accepted answer. ScaleY is the property that you need to change in order to change the height of the ProgressBar. For references [look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.scaley?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-visualelement-scaley)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the most simple solution is to use [Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual)
Then in your XAML, in progress bar set `HeightRequest` property to what you want and use `Visual` property as Material.