# Xamarin change height of progress bar

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to change the height of a progress bar by using a custom renderer like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660605/)

The problem is, when the screen is rotated, the progress bar goes back to normal. Can someone help me?

I am using the same solution:

```
public override void LayoutSubviews()
{
    base.LayoutSubviews();

    var X = 1.0f;
    var Y = 10.0f;

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(X, Y);
    this.Control.Transform = transform;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thnk you need to call the command **SetNeedsLayout** as discussed [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31692/little-confused-with-ios)    . Of course you can also [disable orientation change](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/handling_rotation/).

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged (Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
{
base.OnConfigurationChanged (newConfig);

SetNeedsLayout ();
}
```

Comment: I already tried that. I can't disable orientation because its needed.

Comment: I am sorry. After your response, I searched and it did not worked.