# How to set height of ProgressBar on Xamarin Forms 3.3?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin Forms 3.3, I want change height of ProgressBar. I execute it:
[How to change height of progress bar in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660605/how-to-change-height-of-progress-bar-in-xamarin-forms)
But I can't change height of **ProgressBar**. This is my code:

1) Class custom control ProgressBar:

```
public class ColorProgressBar : ProgressBar
{


public static BindableProperty BarColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(BarColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ColorProgressBar), default(Color));

    public static BindableProperty ProgressTintColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(ProgressTintColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ColorProgressBar), default(Color));

    public static BindableProperty TrackTintColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(TrackTintColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ColorProgressBar), default(Color));

    public Color BarColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(BarColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(BarColorProperty, value);
    }

    public Color ProgressTintColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(ProgressTintColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(ProgressTintColorProperty, value);
    }

    public Color TrackTintColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(TrackTintColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(TrackTintColorProperty, value);
    }

    public float HeightOfProgressBar { get; set; }
    }
```

2) For iOS:

```
public class ColorProgressBarRenderer : ProgressBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ProgressBar> e)
        => iOS.Control.Logger.InvokeAction(() =>
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement == null)
            return;

        if (Control != null)
        {
            UpdateBarColor();
        }
    });

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        => iOS.Control.Logger.InvokeAction(() =>
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == ColorProgressBar.BarColorProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            UpdateBarColor();
        }
    });

    private void UpdateBarColor() => iOS.Control.Logger.InvokeAction(() =>
    {
        var element = (ColorProgressBar) Element;
        if (element == null)
            return;

        Control.TintColor = element.BarColor.ToUIColor();
        Control.ProgressTintColor = element.ProgressTintColor.ToUIColor();
        Control.TrackTintColor = element.TrackTintColor.ToUIColor();
    });

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        var element = (ColorProgressBar)Element;
        if (element == null)
            return;

        var X = 1.0f;
        var Y = element.HeightOfProgressBar > 0.0f ? element.HeightOfProgressBar : 1.0f;

        var transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(X, Y);
        Transform = transform;
    }
}
```

And At View .xaml:

```
<control:ColorProgressBar Grid.Row="1"
                                  HeightOfProgressBar="8.0"
                                  TrackTintColor="{x:Static color:BasePalette.DarkestColor}"
                                  ProgressTintColor="{x:Static color:NeutralPalette.RedColor}"
                                  Progress="{Binding PercentDataValue}">
</control:ColorProgressBar>
```

I test on device run iOS 12.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a comment on the linked SO thread that said:

> To get the iOS renderer to work I needed to change this.Transform = transform; to Control.Transform = transform;

So changing `Transform = transform;` in the `LayoutSubviews` method of the `ColorProgressBarRenderer`  to `Control.Transform = transform;` makes your sample work as expected, i.e the height of the progress bar is changed:

```
    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        var element = (ColorProgressBar)Element;
        if (element == null)
            return;

        var X = 1.0f;
        var Y = element.HeightOfProgressBar > 0.0f ? element.HeightOfProgressBar : 1.0f;

        var transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(X, Y);
        Control.Transform = transform; // <---- change here
    }
```

Comment: Because my project's build save cached. Don't change Transform = transform; to Control.Transform = transform; 
Thanks @jgoldberger