# Blurred progress bar when changing scale on Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, progress-bar

[image]

Changed scale Y=10. In the example I've seen, it grows neatly, but in my case, it became strangely large. Could this be a bug?

Here's a link to what I was referring to.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660605/how-to-change-height-of-progress-bar-in-xamarin-forms)

```
<ContentView
    x:Class="POP.Controls.CtrlBlurProgress"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:Lang="clr-namespace:KLAB.Localizations.Words;assembly=Localizations"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:POP.Controls"
    xmlns:input="clr-namespace:Plugin.InputKit.Shared.Controls;assembly=Plugin.InputKit"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorBackBlur}">


    <StackLayout
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Margin="10,0,10,0"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Label x:Name="xTitle"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="45"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            Text="테스트 중"
            TextColor="{StaticResource ColorText111}"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

        <controls:CtrlProgressBar x:Name="xPrgs"
            Margin="20,0,20,0"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />

        <controls:CtrlButton
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0,0,10,10"
            Clicked="CtrlButton_Clicked"
            HeightRequest="80"
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            Text="{x:Static Lang:General.Cancel}"
            WidthRequest="300" />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

I have added my example code. Please refer to it.

```
<Grid
    x:Class="POP.Controls.CtrlProgressBar"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <ProgressBar x:Name="xPrg"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Margin="10,0,0,10"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Progress="0.8"
        ProgressColor="{StaticResource ColorBack008}"
        ScaleY="15"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

    <Label x:Name="xTxtPercent"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        FontSize="40"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        Text="0 %"
        TextColor="White"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

The progress bar was created as a class (CtrlProgressBar) inherited from grid layout, and this is used in combination with other controls in the CtrlBlurProgress class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [the answer in the link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67391105/17455524)? I have created a new sample to test. Such as:

```
<ProgressBar HeightRequest="50" ScaleY="2" Progress=".5"/>
```

The **HeightRequest** is the Max Height of the progress bar. And the **ScaleY** can change the thick of the progess bar.

So you can use differerents value of the two properties without the custom renderer to get the effect of the progess bar you want. Such as:

```
<ProgressBar HeightRequest="50" ScaleY="2" Progress=".5"/>
<ProgressBar HeightRequest="50" ScaleY="5" Progress=".5"/>
<ProgressBar HeightRequest="80" ScaleY="3" Progress=".5"/>
```

Comment: Is it because of the layout? I can't do the same even if I do it the way you recommended.

Comment: I test it in the stacklayout, could you please show the code about where you put the progressbar in? @하하파파

Comment: Did you try to set a small value for the ProgressBar's ScaleY property? Such as  ScaleY="3". @하하파파

Comment: And you can try to remove ` VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` for the ProgressBar. @하하파파

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar in your project doesn't have a value of the height request. And the value of scale.y is too big.

So you can try to set a value for the height request property. And decrease the value of the scale.y. Such as:

```
<Grid
    x:Class="POP.Controls.CtrlProgressBar"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <ProgressBar x:Name="xPrg"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        HeightRequest="30"
        Margin="10,0,0,10"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Progress="0.8"
        ProgressColor="{StaticResource ColorBack008}"
        ScaleY="5"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

    <Label x:Name="xTxtPercent"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        FontSize="40"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        Text="0 %"
        TextColor="White"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

In addition, I really don't suggest you put the laber and the progress bar in the same row and the same column.

Comment: Did you get the same symptoms when you ran the code I gave you?

Comment: I can't understand what's wrong in your picture.@하하파파

Comment: Did you see the article I referenced? Do you think the shape of the progress bar there and the progress I captured are the same?

The current problem is that the shape is different, and I was curious about why.